# Trouble with SQL and aggregates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

With this query:

```
SELECT SUM(qty) AS sumQty,
       cnetprodid
FROM   quoteitem
WHERE  ordered = 1
       AND sageSOPOrderReturnLineID IS NOT NULL
       AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(cnetprodid))) > 0
       AND cnetprodid LIKE 'S%'
       AND price > 10
       AND created > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP  BY cnetprodid
ORDER  BY SUM(qty) DESC
```

I get one row back per product, the top row has 294 as `sumQty` and 'S10381902' as the `cnetprodid`

Enter this query:

```
SELECT SUM(qty) AS sumQty,
       p.ProdID,
       p.CatID
FROM   quoteitem
       INNER JOIN cds_prod AS p
         ON p.ProdID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = cnetprodid
       INNER JOIN cds_atr AS a
         ON a.ProdID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = p.ProdID
       INNER JOIN lan_cat_sections AS c
         ON c.attID = a.atrID
             OR ( LEN(ISNULL(c.attID, '')) = 0
                  AND c.cat_id LIKE p.CatID + '%' )
                AND ( ( c.[include] = 0
                        AND a.valID NOT IN (SELECT Value
                                            FROM   Split(c.valID, ',')) )
                       OR ( c.[include] = 1
                            AND a.valID IN (SELECT Value
                                            FROM   Split(c.valID, ',')) ) )
WHERE  ordered = 1
       AND sageSOPOrderReturnLineID IS NOT NULL
       AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(cnetprodid))) > 0
       AND cnetprodid LIKE 'S%'
       AND price > 10
       AND created > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP  BY p.ProdID,
          p.CatID,
          a.prodID
HAVING SUM(qty) > 10
ORDER  BY SUM(qty) DESC
```

I get one row per product back but now the row with 'S10381902' as the `ProdID` column has a figure of 8820 for `sumQty`.

All I want is a number for how many products have been sold in the last quarter, not interested in products that have sold less than 10 units, hence the `HAVING` part.

The `COLLATE` is there because the tables come from different databases; one is in `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and another database is in `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce1ed/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely problem is that, by joining to those additional tables, rows in quoteitem become represented more than once in the intermediate result. That is, you have a one-to-many join at some point. SQL Server then obediently sums up those rows multiple times. It's a mistake that's very easy to make.

The simple workaround is to perform your aggregate calculations before doing any one-to-many joins. It might look something like this.

```
SELECT q.sumQty,
       p.ProdID,
       p.CatID
FROM (
        SELECT ProdID, SUM(qty) AS sumQty, ...other columns...
        FROM quoteitem
        GROUP BY ProdID
        HAVING SUM(qty) > 10
    ) q
       INNER JOIN cds_prod AS p
         ON p.ProdID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = cnetprodid
       INNER JOIN cds_atr AS a
         ON a.ProdID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = p.ProdID
       INNER JOIN lan_cat_sections AS c
         ON c.attID = a.atrID
             OR ( LEN(ISNULL(c.attID, '')) = 0
                  AND c.cat_id LIKE p.CatID + '%' )
                AND ( ( c.[include] = 0
                        AND a.valID NOT IN (SELECT Value
                                            FROM   Split(c.valID, ',')) )
                       OR ( c.[include] = 1
                            AND a.valID IN (SELECT Value
                                            FROM   Split(c.valID, ',')) ) )
WHERE  ordered = 1
       AND sageSOPOrderReturnLineID IS NOT NULL
       AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(cnetprodid))) > 0
       AND cnetprodid LIKE 'S%'
       AND price > 10
       AND created > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP  BY p.ProdID,
          p.CatID,
          a.prodID
ORDER  BY q.sumQty DESC
```